# Javascript how to rename a variable in array deconstructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, firebase

I have a deconstructured array of values, as instructed in the docs. (react-firebase-hooks)

```
const [ signInWithEmailAndPassword, loading, error] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

All is fine, but what if I have another hook with the same return keys:

```
const [ signInWithEmailAndPassword, loading, error] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);  
const [ signInWithGoogle, loading, error ] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
```

As I cannot redeclare variables, how would I solve this?

I want to eventually return a spinner, if either loading value is true.

What I tried: Assigning a new variable name inside the deconstructor.

What I was expecting: My expectations were open.

Comment: Have you tried it with `[ signInWithGoogle, loading: googleLoading, error: googleError ]` ?

Left side of colon is the original variable name, right side is the name you want to rename it to.

Comment: Your destructirings are *array* destructurings; the variable names can be anything you want, because the implicit array indexes are the keys for extracting values from the source arrays.

Comment: Array destrcuturing is based on the index. You can name the variables whatever you want

Comment: @adiga ah, of course

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign the names like this:

```js
const [ signInWithEmailAndPassword, loading, error] = [true, true, false];
const [ signInWithGoogle, gLoading = loading, gErr = error ] = 
  [`Hello`, false, `error!`];
console.log( `${signInWithEmailAndPassword}, ${loading}, ${error}\n${
  signInWithGoogle}, ${gLoading}, ${gErr}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to do it like this:

```
const [ signInWithEmailAndPassword, loading, error] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

simply replace it with

```
 const signinObject = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
 // do what you need with loading 
 signinObject[1]
 // do what you need with error
 sigininObject[2]
```

the the destruction only take it out from the array, but this way you keep it as array and refer to its index